# Some rows from DataTable are being lost (C#.net MySQL)

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable

I'm populating the datatable from MySQL database like this

```
        this.data = data;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = DataManagement.GetData("Select * from patient_info where patient_code='" + data + "'");
```

After I populate the textboxes in my form with the values fron DataTable like so:

```
        tbName.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
        tbMiddle.Text = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();
        and so on...
```

But the problem is not all data from the MySQL table can be accessed I keep incrementing the row until I run out of indexes but in the end 4-5 textboxes (out of 20+) stay empty. In other words DataTable contains less rows than there are columns in my MySQL table.

Comment: _less rows than there are culumns_ this makes no sense, please explain

Comment: i mean less data gets extracted into the DataTable than I have in the patient_info table. So less columns in the DataTable than in the MySQL table. Sorry, it might sound like jubberish, it's 3am already =)